# Sorted entries from dictionary to excel using python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am using pandas to write data to an excel file. I want to dump data as it is in one sheet and in second sheet I want it in sorted way. Layers is the key and weights are the values in the dictionary.

for e.g. sheet1 should have the table as below (unsorted) :

[image: Unsorted entries]

and sheet2 should have sorted entries:

[image]

I already tried OrderedDict

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_weights, orient="index")
    df1.columns = ['weights']

    df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(collections.OrderedDict(dict_weights), orient="index")
    df2.columns = ['weights']
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet2', startcol=3)

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter')
    writer.save()
```

The problem is it do the sorting but on both sheets. I just want data to be sorted in sheet2 and in sheet1 it should remain unsorted.

***Expected Output in :***

**Sheet1**

```
Layer;  weights
T1_max_pool;    4
activation_9;   1
sum_9;  3
Merge_2;    4
activation_2;   1
T2_max_pool;    4
```

**Sheet2**

```
Layer;  weights
activation_2;   1
activation_9;   1
Merge_2;    4
sum_9;  3
T1_max_pool;    4
T2_max_pool;    4
```

Any suggestions?? :) Thanks!

Comment: Always helps to have copy-able data in the question instead of images.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I have updated question with ; separated values

Comment: `OrderedDict` just remembers the order of insertion however it is not sorted (at least not in an intuitive way). You can create the `OrderedDict` first and then insert items one after another in a sorted manner. I.e. instead of `OrderedDict(dict_weights)` you can do `sorted_dict = OrderedDict(); for key in sorted(dict_weights): sorted_dict[key] = dict_weights[key]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUIC, you need to use `sort_values` on `Layers` column.

```
In [503]: writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx')

In [504]: df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet1')

In [505]: df.sort_values(by='Layers', ascending=True).to_excel(writer, 'sheet2')

In [506]: writer.save()
```

If you don't want index, use `index=False` while writing to excel.

Comment: I have update and query on the proposed solution. It does the sorting but output is a bit different than expected :   `T1_max_pool |  T2_max_pool | activation_2 | activation_9 | merge_2 | sum_9`. Is it possible it has to do something with Capital and small alphabets?

Answer (score 1):

Change dict into lists and use:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'weights': list2}, index=list1)
df2 = df1.sort_index()
```

`Dict` has its own logic for sorting keys and if you are to `print` it you would see it is not printed as you expect it.